# Remove uncommon unique values from labels in 2 pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas dataframes. df1 and df2.
the label column is the last column.

```
df1.label.unique()
```

output:

```
array([1,  2,  9, 7])

df2.label.unique()
```

output:

```
array([1,  2,  8, 11])
```

How can I delete rows in both dataframes that have uncommon unique values in label column so the two dataframes both have only 1 and 2 label values?

Comment: Just do a inner join on both dfs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without data it is little tricky. However, can you try the code below?

```
df1 = df1[df1.label.isin(df2.label.unique().tolist())]
df2 = df2[df2.label.isin(df1.label.unique().tolist())]
```

Comment: I think OP wants labels that are in both `df1` and `df2`. That is, using `...isin(set(df1.label).intersection(df2.label))`

Comment: @busybear both your codes work the same. are you sure they are different?